# OpenGL Mac OSX vertex shader not linking to fragment shader

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm having problems to compile and execute a simple OpenGL application in Mac OSX 10.9. It works just fine in windows. But in Mac I keep getting some errors while linking the vertex shader to the fragment shader in the shaderProgram.

Here is my console Output.

```
4.1 INTEL-8.26.34

ERROR! could not link the shader program
WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'outColor' not read by fragment shader
ERROR: Input of fragment shader 'inColor' not written by vertex shader
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Here is the Method that I'm using to link both together.

```
GLuint createShaderProgram(GLuint vertexShader, GLuint fragmentShader)
{
    // Create and link the shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram(); // create handle
    if (!shaderProgram) {
    ERROR("could not create the shader program", false);
    return NULL_HANDLE;
    }
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);    // attach vertex shader
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);  // attach fragment shader
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);



    // check to see if the linking was successful
    int linked;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked); // get link status
    if (!linked) {
        ERROR("could not link the shader program", false);
        int maxLength;
        int length;
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
        char* log = new char[maxLength];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, maxLength,&length,log);
        printf(log);

        return NULL_HANDLE;
    }

    return shaderProgram;
}
```

Here is my vertexshader.

```
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 inColor;
layout (location = 3) smooth out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{   
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    outColor = vec4(inColor, 1.0);
}
```

Here is the fragShader

```
#version 410 core
layout (location = 3) smooth in vec4 inColor;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = inColor;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This appears to be a bug with Apple's GLSL compiler. It does not correctly understand Separate Shader Object semantics for matching attributes by their index location when linking a GLSL 4.10 shader. While ratchetfreak's answer will fix your problem, it is not technically correct. The names ***do not need to match*** (or at least if the compiler/linker were doing its job, they would not), this is a problem on Apple's end. You *might* be able to hint the driver into working the way it is supposed to if you add `#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable` to the top of your shader.

Comment: One other thing to consider, if you want Separate Shader Objects to work, you are supposed to re-declare `gl_PerVertex`. So try also adding `out gl_PerVertex { vec4 gl_Position; };`. If even that does not fix it, then you can blame Apple for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the names need to match:

have the name of the output of the vertex shader match the name of the input of the fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 inColor;
smooth out vec4 vertOutColor;
void main()
{   
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    vertOutColor = vec4(inColor, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core
smooth in vec4 vertOutColor;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = vertOutColor;
}
```

Comment: No they don't, this is using Separate Shader Objects. The names do not matter at all. It is the locations that must match. See *Section 4.3.8.1* [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/separate_shader_objects.txt). As best I can tell, this is a GLSL compiler bug. Explicit location matching for stage inputs/outputs is ***core*** in GLSL 4.10.

Comment: Just tried it and now I'm getting different errors. 
`ERROR! Could not compile shader 'vertexShader1.vert'

ERROR! Could not compile shader 'fragmentShader1.frag'
Program ended with exit code: 0`

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri I forgot to rename the variables in the code